# How to setup Vagrant VM for python3/pip and using psycopg2 to connect to a PSQL instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vagrant, pip

I can't seem to figure out how to install all of the dependencies I need to run this python server in a vagrant vm (in lieu of virtualenv for the additional abstraction). I'm using python 3 and I'm using psycopg2 to connect to an AWS RDS instance, and this all works fine on my local machine with all the dependencies installed, but I can't emulate it on a vagrant VM.

I'm using the ubuntu/trusty64 Vagrant box, and I can see python3 and pip3 are installed, but if I try to run pip3 install -r requirements.txt, I get this error:

`Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n' Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vagrant/psycopg`

So then I tried to install `libpq-dev`, and now re-running the same pip installtion yields:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask': Permission denied

Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/Flask/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x8j290vm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vagrant/Flask
```

Comment: Whoops, all I had to do was just run the command as sudo. 

On another note, does anyone know of a vagrant box that already has this stuff provisioned?

Comment: most boxes would be at http://www.vagrantbox.es or https://atlas.hashicorp.com but best would probably to use a provisioner to do all this or do it once and package as a new box